# Setting from jms a custom property in MQRFH2 usr folder

Tags: java, header, jms, ibm-mq

I have a multi tier application where a jms message is sent from a JmsTemplate (Spring) to a WMB Flow. 
In the jms message I could set MQMD headers in order to set meta-info required by the WMB flow listening on an MQQueue.

What I should still do and that is causing issues to me is setting a custom property/header in the JMS message, in **MQRFH2 usr** folder. I want to set there a key named MYKEY with a string value.

What I'm doing in the jms message is this:

message.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.JMS_IBM_MQMD_FORMAT, "MQRFH2");
 message.setStringProperty("MQRFH2.usr.MYKEY", "testvalue");

but I'm getting the error:

> JMSCC0049: The property name 'MQRFH2.usr.MYKEY' is not a valid
>   Java(tm) identifier.; nested exception is
>   com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedMessageFormatException: JMSCC0049: The
>   property name 'MQRFH2.usr.MYKEY' is not a valid Java(tm) identifier

Does anyone knows how to set the MQRFH2 usr customer property named MYKEY into a jms message in usr folder into MQRFH2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you only need to do this:

```
message.setStringProperty("MYKEY", "testvalue");
```

Such call will force using "MQRFH2" format and create a property "MYKEY" in "usr" folder.

The error you have received only states that property name must follow java identifier naming rules, i.e. dots are not allowed there.

Comment: Thanks, this matches with what I can see enabling low level traces:
and that should be done by MQ APIs:

RFH .......�.......�MQSTR ......�...,
<mcd>
 <Msd>jms_text</Msd>
 <Type>1</Type>
</mcd>...�
<jms>
 <Dst>queue:///OUTQUEUE</Dst>
 <Rto>queue://QMGR/REPTOQ</Rto>
 <Tms>1523399291439</Tms>
 <Exp>1523399311439</Exp>
 <Dlv>1</Dlv>
</jms>...�
<usr>
 <MESSAGE_TYPE>1</MESSAGE_TYPE>
 <ReplyToQ>REPTOQ</ReplyToQ>
 <ReplyToQMgr>QMGR</ReplyToQMgr>
 <APPLICATION_NAME>MyJmsClient</APPLICATION_NAME>
 <MYKEY>rO0AB..</MYKEY>

Comment: @caramelleas, if it answers your question - please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't set our own properties in the 'jms' folder but rather you set them in the 'usr' folder.

```
rfh2.setFieldValue("usr", "SomeNum", 123);
rfh2.setFieldValue("usr", "SomeText", "TEST");
```

For a complete example of creating A JMS (MQRFH2) Message in non-JMS Java Application, see here:  http://www.capitalware.com/rl_blog/?p=4823

Comment: It looks that the question is about JMS interface in fact, so there is no direct access to RFH.

Comment: Thanks for the sample, very easy and useful to test so I can compare between the pure jms and the MQ clients.